# Angulars - Different Expression Types on ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-class that does 2 things. Lets say that color is red and type is bmw. Below class
1)Create/Use car-red class
2)Create/Use car-bmw class

```
ng-class="['car-' + car.color, 'car-' + car.type]"
```

But in the same ng-class i also want a third expression that says that class .error must be do something in CSS if "isError" has true value. Like this :

```
 ng-class="{error: isError}"
```

How these 2 different types of expresssion  could be combine?

I try this but with no success :

```
ng-class="['car-' + car.color, 'car-' + car.type, 'error': isError]"
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: class='car-{{car.color}}' ng-class='{error: isError}'

Comment: Thanks but i want all of them in ng-class. Is it possible?

Comment: `['car-' + car.color, 'car-' + car.type, isError ? 'error' : '']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever solution in the comments, or this:

```
ng-class="getClasses(car, isError)"

$scope.getClasses = function (car, isError) {
    var res = ['car-' + car.color, 'car-' + car.type];
    if (isError) {
        res.push('error');
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: When an expression starts growing too much in the dom, I generally prefer to move in to the controller.

Comment: That's a healthy Angular approach.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

> The directive operates in three different ways, depending on which of
>   three types the expression evaluates to:
>
> 1. If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or
>      more space-delimited class names.
> 2. If the expression evaluates to an array, each element of the array
>      should be a string that is one or more space-delimited class names.
> 3. If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair
>      of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a
>      class name.

Meaning, you can't combine in a single expression syntax 2 of the above (in your case, 2 & 3).